# How to edit Formula Bar in macro with variable output?

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a macro that needs to, at one point, click into the formula bar of the current cell, and then press enter. However, when I record this, despite making no edits to the cell, it inputs it based on the text in the cell at the end. The current code is this:

```
Sub Macro36()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveCell.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='C:\Users\User\Documents\[TimeSheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[-3]C[-1]"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The portion from "ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1" onward is where the issue occurs. It automatically does this while recording, rather than having the macro select the formula bar in the cell and then press enter. This is necessary to be able to do because it would allow a workaround for the INDIRECT function not working on closed documents.

Has anyone come across this issue/would know how to fix it? Thank you for any responses.

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but maybe you want just: `ActiveCell.Formula = activecell.value`

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it.